# Rails - controller issue - fails to create Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Have a controller that is failing to create a post.  When I create (try to) a post it gives me an action controller exception:

```
undefined method `Post' for false:FalseClass
```

I have not come across the false:FalseClass before.  Any help is appreciated!

posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.Post.new(params[:post])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

UPDATE:  The user class where I have declared has many is below.  still preventing association and creation of the post.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  attr_accessible :username, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessible :email
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :on => :create

end
```

Comment: This means `current_user` currently holds the value `False` in the `create` method. Make sure `current_user` was correctly created and set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies with the line:

```
current_user.Post.new(params[:post])
```

`current_user` appears to be false, which is possibly not what you expected, but regardless there is no method `Post` on anything that could be returned by `current_user` (since `Post` is a model class).

You might have meant to 'build' a post, with something like:

```
current_user.posts.new(params[:post])
```

This assumes that whatever `current_user` is (a `User`, hopefully?) `has_many :posts`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have added the User model above - I already declared "has_many".

Comment: As I mentioned, the problem is two-fold: `current_user` is false, so start there and get `current_user` returning an instance of `User`. Then you need to fix the line `current_user.Post.new(...)` (since even after `current_user` is a `User` instance, it still will not have a method named `Post`).

Comment: Thanks!  Its up and Running now!